# Primefaces dataTable paginator header not adjusting

Tags: java, css, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

While trying to adjust the resolution of primefaces dataTable, the the paginator header has some issues. How can I sort it? My screen shots are given below. One full screen .[image] and on restore down[image]

Comment: im also in this problem, my table is too small having three columns. But header is much more lengthy than column width.

Comment: I put `style="display:block;overflow-y:none;overflow-x:auto;"` for dataTable for correct screen resolution but no change for the paginator header.

Comment: Report a bug to PF guys.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this:

```
.ui-datatable-tablewrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

This fixed pagination header and footer, and only scroll on data cell.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is discussed [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12188) and [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7685&hilit=fixed%20header&start=10).

I got reasonable results by setting the table to fixed, and adjusting the word wrapping in the table:

```
.ui-datatable thead th {
   white-space: normal;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
.ui-datatable table {
   table-layout:fixed
}
```

And setting the `width` attribute for `p:column` rows.